# how to share the same broadcast-variable-contained filter functions in different pyspark script?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

there are some filter functions like this:

```
def filter1(x):
    if broadcast_variable1.value[x] > 1:
       return False
    return True

def filter2(x):
    if broadcast_variable2.value[x] < 1:
       error_accumulator_variable.add(1)
       return False
    return True
```

these function are included in my main pyspark script. Now I want to split them into a module file for easier maintenance (I have two pyspark scripts for different use but they have the same filters. ), keep the rest in different files.

how to share these-like filter functions in different pyspark script?

Thanks for your generous help！

Answer (score 1):

My basic purpose is to make the program more readable. So I find a simple way to achieve this.

```
def x1(x,broadcast_variable1):
   if broadcast_variable1.value[x] > 1:
   return False

def filter1(x):
   return x1(x,broadcast_variable1)
```

and this can also be rewriten in the currying way(code below is not in python):

```
def x1(broadcast_variable)(x) = 
   if broadcast_variable.value[x] > 1:
   return False
def filter1(x) = x1(broadcast_variable1)
```

now, I can write spark code like this:

```
RDD.filter(filter1).map(map1)....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as argument for functions:

```
def filter1(x, bv):
   ...

def filter2(x, bv):
   ...

broadcast_variable1 = ...

someRDD.filter(lambda x: filter1(x, broadcast_variable1))
```